# How return lambda to thenComparing method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I have a code that I need to modify.
It looks like that:

```
new ComparatorFactory<>(thing -> thing.getLong());
return new ComparatorFactory.bySmthThenLong(things);
```

And the factory class itself:

```
private final Function<T, Long> getLong;
 ComparatorFactory(Function<T, Long> getLong) {
  this.getLong = getLong;
}

Comparator<T> bySmth(Collection<T> things) {
  // Smth happens, then returns comparator. 
}
```

And then I need to chain the `bySmth` method to another method, and these two methods should be separate as sometimes just the first stage is used. 
I need to do something to this `Long` before next round of comparing, so I have a method:

```
private Function<T, Long> preprocessLong(Function<T, Long> getLong) {
 // divide Long by some number and return new function.
}
```

So the creation of this comparator would look like that to my understanding:

```
Comparator<T> bySmthThenLong(Collection<T> things) {
  return bySmth(things).thenComparing(preprocessLong(getLong));
}
```

But I don't understand what the `preprocessLong` method should look like inside. Could you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the JavaDoc for the "Function" Interface you can see, that the method you are overriding with the lambda is the "apply()" method (because it's the only one that is abstract.)
So you call apply inside your new Function like this:

```
private Function<T, Long> preprocessLong(Function<T, Long> getLong) {
   return (thing) -> getLong.apply(thing) / someNumber;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this works, thank you. What if I have a condition so `return condition ? (thing) -> getLong.apply(thing) / someNumber : 0;` to return 0 if not true, how to do that here?

Comment: `return (thing) -> (condition) ? getLong.apply(thing) / someNumber : 0 ;`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!